# Run X application remotely, run GUI on remote host

Tags: ssh, command-line, x11

I have a computer with Ubuntu + a graphical desktop installed where I often run OpenGL applications just to capture the screen and make videos. I only care about the generated video, but to create the OpenGL context, I need to open a window, so I have a program that I can run from the terminal that opens the window, renders stuff with OpenGL and sends the pixel data to an ffmpeg process to make the video and it works. Now, I want to run this video generator remotely via ssh, but when I run the program remotely, window creation fails. I suppose this has something to do with X assuming I want to get some graphical output in the machine I'm connecting from or something like that, I don't know much about this. I just want it to make the video, I don't care about seeing the window, in theory it should be able to open the window in the remote machine as it always does when I run the script locally. Should I set some environment variable like DISPLAY to make this work remotely?

Comment: “… this has something to do with X assuming I want to get some graphical output in the machine I'm connecting from …” Well, I’m not clear — ***is*** that what you want?

Comment: Question seems pretty clear to me, I also want to be able to do this. I want to launch command-line apps that would normally open a window on the host if you were using a keyboard and monitor directly attached, but I want to ssh in from another machine (yet have the window open on the host display).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `DISPLAY` variable to the one where the GUI session (X, Wayland or Mir) is running on the host.

You can use the `who` command to see which display your GUI session is running on (assuming you're already logged in on the remote host's GUI in another session).

Another solution would be to use VNC or SPICE to connect to the remote host for the full desktop.

Comment: This is that I was looking for. Running "export DISPLAY=:1" before running my application made it work as expected.

Comment: export DISPLAY=:0.0 worked for me on a box running Ubuntu 19.04